# You're going so much to beautiful beaches

Tags: word-choice, word-order

Is "You're going so much to beautiful beaches." correct? It sounds a bit weird to me. Would you rephrase it? It means you're going to go to the beach a lot. I just rephrased it but is that one good?

Comment: _You're going to visit so many beautiful beaches!_ Do you mean _many visits_ or _many beaches,_ or both?

Comment: Oh, no! It was about many visits!

Comment: Then the sentence has to be a bit longer: _You're going to visit beautiful beaches so many times!_ or (idiomatic, and "incorrect" grammar) _You're going to visit beautiful beaches so much!_

Comment: Your sentence sounds fine to me, if you're making a prediction about the future. I can imagine it in a context like *You'll like visiting Grandma. She loves to surf so **you're going to go to the beach a lot** – probably every day!*

Answer (score 1):

You almost rephrased it fluently

> You are going to beautiful beaches **a lot**.
>   You are going **so often** to beautiful beaches.

You want to use

> so often

to emphasize it is *habitual*.

Comment: I meant it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a statement about what the future holds, I would avoid using "go" twice in one sentence, and phrase it as

> You will be going to a lot of beautiful beaches.